# Wordpress lowers image quality

Tags: media-library, images

I am uploading to my site large images with media uplader and I want them to have 100% quality but wordpress reduces the quality.  What should I do or what plugin to install to prevent this?

Comment: Is your theme using the original or a resized version?

Comment: I upload them with the media library and i call them with  wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');

Comment: The full size is untouched by default, the quality of that should not be changing.

Comment: But it does this is the problem...

Comment: are you using a core theme and no plugins? have you looked in the uploads folder and verified that filesize is changing?

Comment: Yes it did change but very little ... about 95% of the original size was

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some sort of image optimization plugin installed??

Comment: Well it seems that the problem was another one the I just uploaded the original one and it was the same maybe the other elements of the page makes it look more bright...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress by default compress and lower image quality.  To disable it please enter this code in functions.php file of your theme.

```
add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', create_function( '', 'return 100;' ) );
```

Comment: Correct in approach, but `create_function()` is obsolete. Use modern anonymous function `function() { return 100; }` instead.

Comment: so does WordPress now compress the original size? because it never used to.